# tensorflow has been ineffective training, just a few hundred steps, loss quickly dropped to 0, accuracy reached 100%, has been bothering me for months

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use tensorflow for image classification. There are 5 categories in total, and there are about 300 images in each category.

But in the training process, just a few hundred steps, I have encountered some problems:
1, loss drops to 0, accuracy reaches 100%
2. After adding the verification set (I don't know if the code added is correct), the loss of the verification set is still reduced to 0, and the accuracy of the verification set still reaches 100% or 90+%.
3. When testing with test code, the results are very bad, almost no correctness is identified, but the maximum probability of testing is 90+%.

This is my github code address:
https://github.com/a87871660/Picture_classification

1. Through the tf.summary.image code, you can see that every 100 steps, the input images are different, so is there a problem with input errors?
2. Is the code training properly? Where is the error?
3. Is the calculation code of loss and accuracy wrong?
4. How few data sets are there?

Comment: You may need to focus on one problem area first.  As is, this question is way too broad and asks multiple questions.  Training 5 categories with 1500 images seem to be way too small.  Compared to Cifar 10 which has 60,000 images and 10 categories, this seem to be off by orders of magnitude.  You can use pre-trained model and transfer learning with this small sample size.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try to increase the data set, but what I don't understand most is that training seems to be ineffective, but loss can reach 0 and accuracy can reach 100%.

Comment: You seem to be overfitting.  You model is not actually 100% accurate, but it's saying it is on training data.

Comment: Yes, it is over-fitted on both the training set and the validation set, but I can't find the reason.

Comment: Now, I know what is causing this phenomenon because normalization is not used. But why is it that it is not clear if it is not normalized?

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the Solution here for the benefit of the community.

Problem is resolved if we `Normalize the Data`, i.e., by dividing each Pixel Value by `255`.

By dividing by `255`, the `0-255` range can be described with a `0.0-1.0` range where `0.0` means `0 (0x00)` and `1.0` means `255 (0xFF)`.

Normalization will help you to **remove distortions** caused by *lights* and *shadows* in an image.

Example Code for `Normalization` is shown below:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
X_train_reshaped = tf.reshape(X_train, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
X_test_reshaped = tf.reshape(X_test, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
```